# Jquery Hashtag link system (show what page the user is on)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hashtag

I have a working hashtag link system and I basically want to style the `<li>` to tell a user what page they are on using `background` and `color`. When you click on another list item the jQuery will update the previous page `<li>` CSS back to normal state.

How can I achieve this?

jQuery code:

```
function Init(){
 ShowPage ('#body_home');
}

 function ShowPage(a){
  $(a).css("display","block");
 }

 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").click(function(e){
       if(window.location.href!= 'index.php'){
        window.location.href== 'index.php';
      }else{
        noop();
      }
      $(".page").fadeOut(1000).delay(1500);
      $("#" + $(this).data("page")).fadeIn(1000); e.preventDefault(); return       false;
   });
});
```

HTML code:

```
<ul class="navlist">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="hello.php">Hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So... what's your question? "How can I achieve this?" doesn't qualify

Comment: @Bojangles I am asking how do I make the current page menu item highlight when active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simplified this answer to target the specific behaviour I think you're looking for, but you should be able to implement it for your specific case.

I would create a class and name it `.selected` or `.active`, and assign the styling you want to it. For example:

```
.selected {
    background: #f4a;
    color: #fff;
}
```

When an item is clicked, use jQuery to add the class to that item, and remove the class from all other items. For simplicity, the following example assumes the styling will be applied to the anchor, rather than the list item:

```
$('a').click( function() {
    $('a').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

It would be slightly trickier to target the parent `li`, but the solution would be the same.

[Here's a fiddle demonstrating this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/johntobinme/q79PP/).